# Oracle sql - identify and update primary and secondary rows in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where i need to identify a combination of records which are duplicates and use them to mark and identify which one is primary and which is secondary and then use an additional column to update the keys. This will help me update another child table which has referential integrity. Here's an example

```
Table Member

ID Name Birthdt  MID
1  SK   09/1988  312
2  SK   09/1988  999
3  SL   06/1990  315
4  GK   08/1990  316
5  GK   08/1990  999
```

So from the above table my logic to identify duplicate is -- I do a group by on Name and Birthdate and when MID is 999 i consider that as a duplicate

so I created another temp table to capture dups.

```
Table member_dups
ID NAME BIRTHDT MID M_flg M_Key

1  SK   09/1988      P        1
2  SK   09/1988      S        1
4  GK   08/1990      P        4
5  GK   08/1990      S        4
```

For my table member_dups im able to load the duplicate records and update the flag . however I'm finding it difficult to get the right M_KEY for records marked as secondary. If i can achieve that then I can take that record and update the other table accordingly.

Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic right the records that had MID = 999 is the secondary in member_dups.

If so you should be able to use an simple update with a join:

```
update member_dups
set m_key = m.id
from member_dups md
inner join Member m on m.name = mb.name and m.birthdt = mb.birthdt
where mb.m_flg = 's' and m.mid = 999
```

**This example uses MSSQL syntax and thus isn't valid Oracle syntax**, but you should get the idea, and hopefully you know Oracle better than I do. I'll try to work out the correct Oracle syntax and update the answer soon.

EDIT: I think this is the working Oracle syntax, but I haven't been able to test it:

```
MERGE INTO member_dups 
USING 
(
  SELECT id,
         name,
        birthdt
  FROM Member
  where m.mid = 999
) m ON (m.name = mb.name and m.birthdt = mb.birthdt and mb.m_flg = 's')
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET member_dups.m_key  = m.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I cant really use the condition m.mid=999. I have simplified the scenario to make it simple. There are various conditions to identify the primary and secondary record. i'm trying for a self join on the dupl table and update the keys.

Comment: @user1751356 Oh ok. If you want a working answer accurate details can be helpful :)

Comment: update member_dups
SET p_flg = 'S' where M_ID like '999%' or M_ID LIKE '000%' or M_ID LIKE '%0000'

Comment: Basically i have a lot of columns and records to identify and i'm loading the dups table once I identify them based on the group by combinations.  then I update the member_dups with the below condition. 
SET m_flg = 'S' where M_ID like '999%' or M_ID LIKE '000%' or M_ID LIKE '%0000'. Now when i have the primary and secondary records the next task is to append the right key.